# Windows 10 Live Tile Branding Logo extremely small

Tags: uwp, live-tile, branding

I have the following problem. I create Secondary Tiles within my application and brand them with name and logo. Compared to other apps I have pinned the logo seems to be extremely small. I created the badge logo and all logos with targetsize with no border. Can anyone tell me which picture is exactly used for the branding logo?

The tile is created like this:

```
string tileId = "MySecondaryAppTile"
string displayName = "MyApp";
string tileActivationArguments = "MyApp activated from Secondary tile";

Uri square71x71Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square71x71Logo.png");
Uri square150x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square150x150Logo.png");
Uri wide310x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Wide310x150Logo.png");
Uri square310x310Logo = new Uri("ms-

TileSize newTileDesiredSize = TileSize.Wide310x150;

SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(tileId,
                                                displayName,
                                                tileActivationArguments,
                                                square150x150Logo,
                                                newTileDesiredSize);

 if (!(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent(("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))))
 {
      secondaryTile.VisualElements.Wide310x150Logo = wide310x150Logo;
      secondaryTile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnWide310x150Logo = true;
      secondaryTile.VisualElements.Square310x310Logo = square310x310Logo;
      secondaryTile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare310x310Logo = true;
 }

 secondaryTile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;

 secondaryTile.RoamingEnabled = false;

 Windows.Foundation.Rect rect = FloorPage.GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender);
Windows.UI.Popups.Placement placement = Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Below;
bool isPinned = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateForSelectionAsync(rect, placement);
```

The Tile notification like this:

```
TileContent tileContent = new TileContent()
{
   Visual = new TileVisual()
   {
        **Branding = TileBranding.NameAndLogo**,

        TileMedium = new TileBinding()
        {
             Content = CreateTileBindingContent()
        },

        TileWide = new TileBinding()
        {
             Content = CreateTileBindingContent()
        },

        TileLarge = new TileBinding()
        {
            Content = CreateTileBindingContent()
        }
    }
};
TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(tileContent.GetXml());
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(tileId).Update(notification);
```

To be shure I mean the following logo:

[image: Tile branding name and logo]

Comment: How did you create the secondary tile? Could you please post your code?

Comment: I added all information. Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, was your question "Why is the branding logo so small?" or "Which asset is used for the branding logo?" The answer to the first question is that it's just how it was designed. I'm looking for the answer to the second question. If you clarify I can edit your question for you - I'd rather not have to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: My question is a combination of both. Which asset is used is answered already but as you mention in your own post below the size of the logo still does not match the size of the most system apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use `Square44x44Logo` as Branding logo. So make sure your assert file looks right(e.g. the transparent part of your logo should be as less as possible).

Comment: Thanks I used the 75% rule from this guideline ["Guidelines for tile and icon assets"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx) for the Square44x44Logo now and it looks way better but still smaller than in the system apps

Comment: What's strange is that this seems to be the case for apps like Mail, Store, Xbox, as well as all third-party apps, whose tile branding logos clearly appear different from the targetsize-16 asset (at 100% scale anyway), but for apps like Calendar (as shown in the question) and some of the MSN apps, the branding logos appear identical to the targetsize-16 logo and it seems like they might actually be using that asset directly.